# Android 14 SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM default disabled and user runtime permission is not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, runtime-permissions, android-14

Android 14 SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM default disabled. At the same time, we are asking for a user grant. It is not showing the permission popup system dialog. Do we still need to ask for support from the settings page instead of the runtime permission dialog?

Comment: Show how you are requesting the permissions because by the sounds of it you are not doing the right thing, its not a dialog that comes up for this one